# 2d images to 3d(reconstruction)

Tags: opencv, 3d, emgucv

I need your help and advice. The question consists of the following items: there are pictures from a chamber that stands in a room in the strictly fixed place(a chamber turns about the axis) . How to combine all these pictures in one so that there was an effect as though we see it with the eyes? There are all pictures of foreshortening (left, right, top, bottom and other foreshortening) of room from one point. I think that I need to use 3d calibration and reconstructionin emgu(opencv). Your help and advice are needed. And also some example of using. Maybe someone has already faced such problem. I’ll be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various methods for 2D to 3D reconstruction, most commonly used are

1. Stereography (This method requires two camera placed at some offset)
2. Laser Projection based such as Kinect or Lidar or line laser based.
3. SFM (structure from motion).

Taking all shots from one point wont give you any 3D information, since there need to have some parallex to determine the difference in depth(unless you are using laser projection).

it is better if you selfstudy relevent topics first before asking questions on the forum, to show other that you really did your part.

Comment: Yeah you dont need a laser for static objects a overhead projector and a camera is enough.